# Relationship of transpose of linear mapping and Riesz isomorphism

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products, riesz-representation-theorem

How do I show the following:

Be $Z$ a limited Euclidean vector space with the inner product space $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ and $\Phi : Z \to Z^*, z \mapsto \langle \cdot,z \rangle$ (Riesz representation theorem). For $f \in \mathcal{L}(Z,Z)$ the following relationship holds:

$^tf = \Phi^{-1} \circ f^* \circ \Phi$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x,y \in Z$. Then :
\begin{align}
\langle x, \Phi^{-1}\circ f^* \circ \Phi(y) \rangle &= f^*\circ\Phi(y)(x) \\
&= \Phi(y)\circ f(x)\\
&= \langle f(x) ,y \rangle \\
&= \langle x, f^t(y) \rangle
\end{align}

Therefore $ \Phi^{-1}\circ f^* \circ \Phi = f^t$

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the first line to me? I don't really get why this is the case: $\langle x, \Phi^{-1}\circ f^* \circ \Phi(y) \rangle = f^*\circ\Phi(y)(x)$

Comment: This is just the definition of $\Phi$: for $x,y \in Z$, $\Phi(x)(y) = \langle y,x\rangle$. Therefore, for $x \in Z, \theta \in Z^*$, $ \theta(y) = \langle y,\Phi^{-1}(\theta) \rangle$

Comment: Aaaah, got it! Thanks!